# Sofortüberweisung for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment, magento-2.1

Is there an extension or any other possibility to implement the german payment service "Sofortüberweisung"?

There does not seem to be any information online.

Comment: Not yet. You might call SOFORT and ask for the technical department. They might give you a answer on this. HINT: they will not have any date yet, since Mage2 has not a big market in the EU yet, its all Mage1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official extension can be downloaded here:

https://www.sofort.com/integrationCenter-ger-DE/integration/shopsysteme/Magento-Community/#14098-sue

Answer (score 0):

You can Adyen, they support a great amount of Payment methods, as far as I know also SOFORT. And have a [Magento 2 extension on GitHub](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-magento2).